# Rails, Audit Log in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, audit-logging

I have a Model called `file.rb` that handles a files data table. This was done so that I can upload excel files from a file `index.html.erb`, and have the file name stored, see who uploaded the file, when it was created, etc(just tracking the files). These Excel files have many rows and each row have a bottle object with many attributes. During the create method, after save, I send the uploaded file to another model `bottle.rb'.

The `bottle.rb` model handles opening the Excel file and importing the information from the Excel file into the bottles data table.

I would like to be able to create an audit log with a message telling me success or failure of an uploaded excel file. Once the file passes the validations, I would like to see how many updates and new inserts to the bottles table. And be able to see this in the view where I upload the Excel file. I appreciate any helpful tips! I made an activity feed but for the entire application, but I am unsure how to go about to do this task.

Comment: Here is a guide to loging in rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#what-is-the-logger-questionmark You could just create a new audit.log file to write to.  Another thing you might want to consider is renaming your file model.  File is a class in ruby's standard library.

Comment: @jphager2 Thanks for the advise. As I was reading the loging in rails, but as I understand, that way of doing that, it writes it to a log. What I am trying to do is create a history log that people can see in the view right after they imported an excel file. I would like the history log to show how many rows where either updated or added. Thanks for the help and I'll be sure to rename the model.